# Android record mediaplayer (stream)

Tags: java, android, stream, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I play the music (internet radio stream) in a MediaPlayer. I would like to save the datastream (or the waveform) to a file, and play it back later. Does it have SDK support? I did not found, AudioRecorder and MediaRecorder is only good for mics and voice uplink/downlink.

So, how to save the data played by mediaplayer? And how to play it back? I need an API 8/9  to API 16 solution.